# Comparing two similar videos of different run time length

Tags: algorithm, video, ffmpeg

I have two videos of a single selenium automation script. One is a baseline video and I want to compare the second video with this baseline video. In comparison I want to capture the screenshots of the frames that are not matching.

The problem is that the videos might not be of same size and run time as the running of scripts depends on network.

I have tried ffmpeg for this, but that didn't result in any fruitful result. Can anyone guide me in a right direction on how to get a head-start in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Comparing screenshots... you need a good algorithm just for this. I mean, videos usually are "compressed" with mpeg2, mpeg4 or similar methods, which are data-lose compress methods. So any minimal change in the original frames will result in different "bmp" images.

I can only figure out starting with a frame in video1, iterating through video2 until a frame is "same as", advance to next frame in video1, searching for this frame in video2, etc.